# group_by date column in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

After extensive searching on this issue, I still cannot find the solution. I have a simple data frame with 43 rows and 2 columns. My first column contains two dates. The first date is printed 19 times and the other 24 times. The second column is temperature. I want to find the max and min temperature by date, but my code keeps printing the entire data set's max and min.

Data:

```
Date <- c(rep(x = "2017-05-18", each= 19), rep(x = "2017-05-19", each= 24))


Temperature_F <- c(35, 35, 42, 49, 57, 63, 64, 67, 70, 71, 72, 71, 72, 70, 66, 61, 57, 54, 50, 49, 45, 44, 44, 42, 40, 39, 47, 53, 61, 67, 69, 
    72, 75, 76, 77, 76, 77, 75, 71, 66, 62, 58, 54)

NWS_temps1 <- data.frame(Date, Temperature_F)
```

Here is my dplyr code that keeps giving me the max and min for the entire temperature column when I think it should be giving me the max and min temperature by date.

```
NWS_temps1 <- tbl_df(NWS_temps1)

 NWS_temps1 %>%
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  summarise(Tmax = max(Temperature_F), Tmin= min(Temperature_F))
```

The output I get is:

```
 Tmax Tmin
  77   35
```

When I am hoping for:

```
Date        Tmax Tmin
2017-05-18   72   35
2017-05-19   77   39
```

I don't understand why Date isn't be grouped as it should. I've attempted changing Date to a factor as it is here, character, date object, and even POSIXct, but my result is always the total data frame max and min.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `group_by`, not `group_by_`, which is for standard evaluation.

Comment: That was an error on my part as I have tried group_by. Both group_by and group_by_ produce the same result :/

Comment: I tested your code and replace the `group_by_` with `group_by`. It worked.

Comment: I also used the code below to produce the results below.

Comment: Something must have been off with my R session as I got the correct result upon opening the session again after closing it. Really weird. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: You know what I think---I just had the same issue---is that accidentally `plyr` might have been loaded. Then it collapses down to taking summary over the whole dataframe. I tend to use `dplyr::summarise` every time but forgot this one instant. I don't normally load `plyr` but another package must have called it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using the standard evaluation version `group_by_()` instead of the NSE version `group_by()`. Try it without the underscore:

```r
NWS_temps1 %>%
    group_by(Date) %>% 
    summarise(Tmax = max(Temperature_F), Tmin= min(Temperature_F))

#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>         Date  Tmax  Tmin
#>        <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 2017-05-18    72    35
#> 2 2017-05-19    77    39
```

Comment: That's interesting. I've tried both and I keep getting the same result. I'm surprised yours worked. I'm going to try closing my R session and opening again. No idea why this isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

```
NWS_temps1 %>%
group_by(as.character(Date)) %>% 
summarise(Tmax = max(Temperature_F), Tmin= min(Temperature_F))
```

Comment: `as.character` is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

The answers provided by others using `dplyr` should work. However, if for some reasons `dplyr` is not working. Here is a solution using `tapply` from base R.

```
dt <- data.frame(Date = unique(NWS_temps1$Date),
                 Tmax = tapply(NWS_temps1$Temperature_F, NWS_temps1$Date, FUN = max),
                 Tmin = tapply(NWS_temps1$Temperature_F, NWS_temps1$Date, FUN = min))
```

Comment: thank you, i will keep this as reference for the future!

Answer (score 1):

There are `summarise` functions in both the `dplyr` and `plyr` packages. I'm guessing that the order in which the packages were loaded meant that the `plyr` version of the function was being loaded, which would give you the results you were seeing. You can manually specify which version of the function you want to use by prepending the package name like this: `dplyr::summarise(...)`.

```
# Specify the plyr version:
> NWS_temps1 %>%
+   group_by(Date) %>% 
+   plyr::summarise(Tmax = max(Temperature_F), Tmin= min(Temperature_F))
  Tmax Tmin
1   77   35

# Specify the dplyr version:
> NWS_temps1 %>%
+   group_by(Date) %>% 
+   dplyr::summarise(Tmax = max(Temperature_F), Tmin= min(Temperature_F))
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Date        Tmax  Tmin
  <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>
1 2017-05-18    72    35
2 2017-05-19    77    39
```

Edit: I've just noticed that Kim had already posted this as a comment on the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to replicate the original `group_by()` issue when converting a date/time field represented as number to a date with `as.Date()` - this might happen when working with a date/time field imported from an Excel file because Excel stores dates as numbers.

```
library(dplyr)

dt = c(43167.86, 43167.59, 43167.59, 43167.23, 43182.60, 43168.17, 43182) 
df <- data_frame(date = dt)

df %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, origin = '1899-12-30')) %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  summarize(obs = n())
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  date         obs
  <date>     <int>
1 2018-03-08     1
2 2018-03-08     2
3 2018-03-08     1
4 2018-03-09     1
5 2018-03-23     1
6 2018-03-23     1
```

That gives mulitple versions of the same dates for '2018-03-08' and '2018-03-23'. One line of '2018-03-08' has two observations because there are two '43167.59' - the same date and time, while there are two other 43167, but both with different times. This appears that it could be a `dplyr` related issue as `table(as.Date(df$date, origin = '1899-12-30'))` works as expected.

One option is using `lubridate::ymd()`:

```
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, origin = '1899-12-30')) %>% 
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  summarize(obs = n())
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  date         obs
  <date>     <int>
1 2018-03-08     4
2 2018-03-09     1
3 2018-03-23     2
```

Another (crude) solution is to convert the date to a character, and then back if you want to keep it as a date:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, origin = '1899-12-30')) %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(as.character(date))) %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  summarize(obs = n())
```

The best solution might be stepping back a step and setting the column type as a date when importing with `readxl::read_excel()`. That will import the field as a date/time, but then `as.Date()` and `group_by()` will work as expected. Example from the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/vignettes/cell-and-column-types.html):

```
library(readxl)

df <- read_excel(readxl_example("type-me.xlsx"), sheet = "date_coercion",
                 col_types = c("date", "text"))
```